# Deploy Go/Golang REST Web API on production

Tags: web-services, rest, nginx, go

I am writing a backend web api for a mobile app. It should support HTTPS. Most of my experience in .NET, but for this one I want to use Go/Golang. I have a sample service ready, now I need to make sure that it is production ready.
In .NET I will just use IIS, but I have no clue what would be a good approach for Go.
Should I have nginx as reverse proxy, or I better use FastCGI ? And how to make sure that my go app is up and will run on system reboot ? should I use upstart or something similar ?

Comment: I've had good results using Nginx on top of a Go API; Nginx takes care of SSL and adding support for SPDY etc is easy. Having Nginx handle deflate/gzip, SSL will also simplify your Go API code.

Comment: Do you use nginx as reverse proxy or you run FastCGI ? And how do you keep your go application running ?

Comment: Nginx as a reverse proxy is da bomb, works great for me as well, with a workload of hundreds of sustained RPS

Comment: I know it is off topic, but what framework did you guys use ?

Comment: Reverse proxy as Not_a_Golfer says - personally I'm just using vanilla net/http

Comment: @Tamerlane I'm using a tiny helper framework I wrote on top of net/http that just adds stuff like automatic json encoding and timing measurements, and the schema mapper from gorilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using Nginx FastCGI with a Go webservice - they work well together. It's no harder to set up than HTTP reverse proxying - except for having to learn how to do it. The performance ought in principle to be a lot better, but I have no measurements to justify that hunch. My web service can work in both HTTP mode and FastCGI mode (one or other at a time), so I suppose I ought to do some benchmarking (note to self!).

If you want proper system startup (and you should), you need to learn how init scripts work. I sometimes cheat and start with an existing working script someone else wrote for a similar application and customise it to work with mine.

Answer (score 0):

I've used nginx as a reverse proxy for my Go projects. I've found that it's a lot easier to set up useful server settings such as TLS, compression, etc., in nginx rather than as a pure Go server.

Keeping it alive on server reboot is a more complicated question. I would suggest learning how to write a script/whatever for your server's init daemon and just doing it that way.